# Angularjs Custom Directive validations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

Writing angularjs custom directive for some input validations like not allow input to have more than 10 characters and not allow input to have leading or trailing whitespaces, written following code

```
angular.module("angulareDir", [])
.directive("myDirective", function() {    
    return{
             restrict: 'A',
             link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

                var reg = /^\s+|\s+$/g;

                angular.element(elem).on("keypress", function(e) {
                var eMessage = angular.element("#message-error");

                    if (elem.val().length >= 10) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                    }
                    if (reg.test(elem.val()) === true) {
                        eMessage.show();
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
             }
            };

});
```

It works fine for input having value more than 10 characters and as expected doesn't allow user to type after 10 characters but it doesn't work on leading/trailing spaces, i'm not sure if my regular expression wrong??

use case doesn't work for me when I've spaces before and after string like

> space space space "hello world" space space space

**Note: I only want to allow user to have spaces between the string but not at the beginning and at the end of the string and i want to check this when user starts typing in the input box**

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS trims the input by default, so you need to use ng-trim="false" in order to pass leading and trailing whitespace to your pattern.
See the documentation for details [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)